# irreducibility of the polynomial $ x^4 +1 $

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, fields, number-fields

Let $K$ be a field. We consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^4 + 1$. It is known that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but reducible over any finite field. Thus $ f(x)$ is reducible over any field $ K $ having  positive characteristic.

I am interested in determining for which fields $f(x)$ remains irreducible, based on the case  $\text{char}(K) = 0$.

Comment: It's irreducible iff $-1$ and $-2$ are non-squares in the field. For a finite field $\mathbf{F}_q$, this holds iff $q$ is 7 mod 8.

Comment: @YCor K is a finite field then  f(x)  can never irreducible.

Comment: would you give me a factorization modulo 7?

Comment: @YCor How about $(x^2+3x+1)(x^2-3x+1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I was not careful enough. The correct statement is that this is irreducible iff $-1$, $2$ and $-2$ are all non-squares, and indeed this is not possible in a finite field (and hence in a positive char. field).

Comment: If $p$ is odd then $p^2-1$ is divisible by $8$; if $p=2$ then $x^4+1=(x+1)^4$.

Comment: More generally, one can give a criterion for when the polynomial $X^n-a$ is irreducible over a field. See [this note](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~marc.hindry/X%5En-a.pdf) of Hindry. See also Lang, Algebra (3rd edition), Chapter 6, Section 9.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Among $-1$, $2$, and $-2$, there are $0$, $1$ or $3$ squares. This determines the irreducible factorization of $X^4+1$.

1. If none is a square, it is irreducible;
2. If only $-1=i^2$ is a square, the irreducible factorization is $(X^2-i)(X^2+i)$;
3. If only $-2=u^2$ is a square, the irreducible factorization is $(X^2+uX-1)(X^2-uX-1)$;
4. If only $2=v^2$ is a square, the irreducible factorization is $(X^2+vX+1)(X^2-vX+1)$;
5. If all are squares and char is $\neq 2$, the polynomial is split, with simple roots $i^k(1+i)/v$, $k=0,1,2,3$;
6. If the char is 2 (so all are squares), the polynomial is $(X-1)^4$.

---

Added: here's a proof. The char. 2 case (Case 6) being trivial, I assume $2\neq 0$. First, if there is a root $\theta$ in the field, then the polynomial splits with distinct roots $\theta^k$, $k=\pm 1,\pm 3$ (with $\theta^{-3}=-\theta$). In particular, if the polynomial is not irreducible, it is product of two degree 2 polynomials.

If $\theta$ is a root (possibly in a larger field) and the polynomial is not irreducible, the polynomial therefore splits with one of the following factors: $A=(X-\theta)(X-\theta^{-1})$, $B=(X-\theta)(X-\theta^3)$, $C=(X-\theta)(X+\theta)$. We observe that $A=X^2+vX+1$ with $v^2=2$, $B=X^2+uX-1$, $C=X^2-i$ with $v^2=2$, $u^2=-2$, $i^2=-1$. Hence if $2$ resp $1$ resp $-1$ is a square then $A$ resp $B$ resp $C$ yields a factorization in the ground field. If all are squares, $(1+i)/u$ is a root and the polynomial is totally split.

Conversely if $-2$ has no square root then $A$ is not a polynomial in the ground field and hence the polynomial is not totally split, etc, and if none of the three is a square, none of the possible degree two factors occurs and hence the polynomial is irreducible. Thus all of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are proved.

NB in char. $3$, we have $2=-1$ but this is no contradiction: just Cases 2 and 4 are excluded (and 1 is excluded as well). But actually in char $p>0$, for given $p$, at most one of 2, 3, 4 is possible and 1 is excluded, so char. $3$ is not really special.

Comment: PS for $q$ odd prime power, the field $\mathbf{F}_q$ belongs to resp. Case 2, 3, 4, 5 according to whether $q$ is resp. 5, 3, 7, 1 modulo 8.

Comment: For a local field of char. zero and residual field of odd order, the case is the same as the residual field, in particular $X^4+1$ is not irreducible. However, for $\mathbf{Q}_2$, none of $-1,2,-2$ is a square (since these are not squares mod 8) and hence $X^4+1$ is irreducible.